# PHP/MySQL - Fill empty values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I would like to show jFlot bars for apache hits.
Every day I parse the access.log files and write them into a mysql database.
Now I would like to filter for days,weeks,etc.

Example for a day: `SELECT HOUR(`h_time`) AS hour, COUNT(*) as zugriffe FROM zugriffe WHERE h_server = $serverID AND h_date = '$datum' GROUP BY hour`

One problem: There aren't hits any hour, so I get the following from mysql:

8   2

13  3

15  1

Now I'm filling the 'pageviews' variable with the following sql-statement:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++){
    $row = $mydb->fetchRow();
    echo '['.$row['hour'].','.$row['zugriffe'].'],';
}
```

How to do that empty values will be filled up with: ['hour',0]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$day=array();
while ($row = $mydb->fetchRow()){
   $day[$row['hour']] = $row['zugriffe'];
}
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++){
   if (isset($day[$i])){
      echo '['.$i.','.$day[$i].'],';
   }
   else {
      echo '['.$i.',0],';
   }
}
```

Comment: You forgot a ')' but works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: off-topic: the for-content could shortly look like `echo (isset($day[$i]?'['.$i.','.$day[$i].'],':'['.$i.',0],');`